# What is the use of "Spark" in the sample code provided at google plus quick start for java

Tags: jakarta-ee

Can someone tell me what is the use of this piece of code?

```
import static spark.Spark.get;   
import static spark.Spark.post;
```

provided in the sample program at [google plus quick start for java](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java)

And what is "spark"?

Answer (score 1):

```
import static spark.Spark.get;
```

This is called static import . The static import declaration imports static members from classes and allowing them to be used without class reference.

And as per the [Google site](https://code.google.com/p/spark-java/):

> Spark is a Sinatra inspired micro web framework for Java.

And the [SparkJava documentation](http://www.sparkjava.com/why.html) says :

It is micro web framework for quickly creating web applications in Java with minimal effort.

> Spark's intention is not to compete with Sinatra, or the dozen of clones in different languages (Grafitti, Nancy, Flask, Sammy etc...). Its intention is to be used by Java developers that want or are required to develop in pure Java.
>
> Spark focuses on being as simple and straight-forward as possible, without the need for cumbersome (XML) configuration, to enable very fast web application development in pure Java with minimal effort. (It’s a totally different paradigm when compared to the overuse of annotations for accomplishing pretty trivial stuff seen in JAX-RS).